# How can I create a virtual environment with specific Python version in Windows?

Tags: python, python-venv

I have Python 3.10 in my machine. But I want to use 3.8 for a project. How can I create a virtual environment with Python 3.8 ?

Comment: `py -3.8 -m venv your_venv_directory`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this command:

```
virtualenv venv --python=python3.8
```